# How to Connect Raspberry Pi to WiFi Network without keyboard / Monitor but via Putty at first installation?

Tags: noobs, pi-3b+

I have got a new **Raspberry Pi 3 B+** model. I'm using **Noobs** package for Pi OS.

Now, I have the only laptop. So, after seeing some online tuts I'm thinking, can I configure WiFi in Pi via terminal. I've one WiFi router. I've seen that, in order to connect headlessly via Putty, I need to connect my Pi to the WiFi router. And that's by using Monitor and Keyboard. Like, Insert SD card in Pi and after attaching Keyboard and mouse and HDMI monitor to Pi, just power the Pi.

After it boots up, we went to configuration setting and enables SSH and VNC ( if I need it later). And from WiFi settings connect the Pi to a router. And after connecting to WiFi, Open up the terminal and type `ifconfig` and then in `wlan0` section, we can see the IP address and we literally use it to access Pi via Putty from the remote computer.

Now, as I have know Monitor or Keyboard available, Is there any way I can connect my Raspberry Pi to my WiFi router and get the IP address to access Pi via Putty from the remote computer.

Answer (score 1):

Do **not** use NOOBS if you need a **100% headless installation**. That is, if you can't connect a real display and mouse/keyboard to your Raspberry Pi before using it for the first time. Use Etcher and image files instead. Download Etcher and install it, then download the Raspbian image file. Use Etcher to write the image file to your SD card. Eject and re-insert your card.

You need to add two files to your SD card now: **ssh.txt** and **wpa_supplicant.conf**

Contents of **wpa_supplicant.conf** :

```
network={
 # country code is mandatory or the Pi will violate EMI regulations of multiple countries
 # GB=Great Britain
country=GB
ssid="your ssid"
psk="your password"
}
```

ssh.txt should be left empty. If you want, you can even rename it to just "ssh" (without the extension).

Comment: What do you mean by 100% headless installation and not using NOOBS?

Comment: @flakeshake - You need a *full* wpa_supplicant.conf for Raspbian Stretch, including 'country' line, etc.

Comment: @Dirk so is there more information do I need to include `wpa_supplicant.conf` file? And, one last thing, let's say I used Raspbian Stretch and after burn the image file into SD card and create two files manually. Then I power the pi and then using Advanced IP scanner, Will I get the IP address of my Pi, so that I can use it on Putty for remote access the Pi?

Comment: You can probably get the IP addr from "Advanced IP scanner", but there are simpler ways - [for example](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/FindMyPi.md)

Comment: what about **Timezone** along with Wifi Country,  SSID, PSK?

Comment: There is two option in **Timezone** section. How to set it on `wpa_supplicant.conf` file? Moreover, after booting there are two options pop up, like **Rasbian** and **LibraOffice**. Without monitor and keyboard or simply saying no external device, How to handle this?